# jQuery ajax is not working on Mozilla only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mozilla

I have following script

```
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url:"views/jquery/js/private/visual_constructor/proxy.php",
   data:null,
   timeout:55000, 
   dataType:"xml",
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
         alert("error="+XMLHttpRequest+" error2="+textStatus+" error3="+errorThrown);
   },
   success:function(response){                      
         alert('sucess');
   }
});
```

and the content of the proxy.php is following.

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: application/xml');
   echo file_get_contents('http://server.name/somefile.php');
?>
```

It connects to another server where `somefile.php` generates some xml content and prints it.

It works perfectly in Chrome, but in Mozilla it shows me my error alert.

What is wrong here?

**update 1**

I am using firebug and it says that everything is just OK. Even it shows the response from the server. And here is what my error alert prints:

```
error=[object XMLHttpRequest] error2=parsererror error3=parsererror
```

**update 2**

When I open http://server.name/somefile.php from the Mozilla it shows me this message:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://authoringtool/views/jquery/js/private/visual_constructor/proxy.php
Line Number 8, Column 94:  <xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Network     Type</xs:documentation></xs:annotatin>
```

But again when I open it from Chrome it doesn't show me the error but prints the content of the somefile.php

Comment: You can use the "Console" tab of firebug to guess what is going on. What do textStatus and errorThrown variables contain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing a cross-server request (more importantly, a cross-domain request ), and as such,  you need to do extra security stuff.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Server-Side_Access_Control

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/

*Firebug*

Also, with Firebug, debugging is better as objects, then you can inspect the returned objects.

```
console.log({ "error": XMLHttpRequest, "error2": textStatus,  "error3": errorThrown });
```

Comment: But in order to avoid this problem of cross-domain request I created proxy.php file which connects to other server and prints its content. So from ajax I am getting the content of my proxy.php file which is in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content type from the query itself:

```
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url:"views/jquery/js/private/visual_constructor/proxy.php",
   data:null,
   timeout:55000,
   contentType: "application/xml;charset=UTF-8",
   dataType:"xml",
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
         alert("error="+XMLHttpRequest+" error2="+textStatus+" error3="+errorThrown);
   },
   success:function(response){                      
         alert('sucess');
   }
});
```

Comment: Showing error message like this:
error=[object XMLHttpRequest] error2=parsererror error3=parsererror

Answer (score 0):

You open with:

```
<xs:annotation>
```

And close with:

```
</xs:annotatin>
```

Fix the spelling error and the problem should go away.